# Ubuntu Touch for iPhones, iPods and iPads?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ipod, iphone, ipad, porting

Is there any sign of Ubuntu Touch for iThingys in the near future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will not happen, as Apple does not officially allow the installation of custom roms. If ever, it will be an unofficial community-port.

Comment: Ah well . . .  ;)